# what is the default value for "Timestamp with zone" in pgsql?

Tags: postgresql

I am using following code to have default value if column has null value.
PostgreSQL version : 9.3

```
COALESCE(LastLoginTimestamp,'')
```

Error:

```
invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: ""
```

What I need to do in order to have default/empty value if LastLoginTimestamp is null.

Comment: `COALESCE` shouldn't really be used for "default" but for the *"when it is `NULL`, it should be something else"* case. That *something else* need not always be the same, and you don't always need to convert `NULL` to a so-called 'default' value. `NULL` is the universal state indicator to mean the lack-of-value (*e.g. the user has never logged in before*). Your program should check for `null` and act appropriately, instead of having the database convert `NULL` into some arbitrary 'default' value.

Comment: Sometimes you may want to convert `NULL` to something else for **business logic purposes**. In these cases you may use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, `NOW()`, `TIMESTAMP '-infinity'` or anything else that's a valid `timestamp` depending on the end purpose.

Answer (score 3):

There's no valid interpretation of `''` as a timestamp; `CAST('' AS TIMESTAMP)` will fail too. For the good reason that `''` is a nonsense input for a timestamp and should not produce anything except an error.

This idea of the empty string being converted to a default value came fro MySQL and MyISAM back in the day when there was no transaction support so MySQL couldn't afford to fail since it couldn't rollback; it was better to make up dummy data for invalid inputs. Needless to say that doesn't apply to PostgreSQL (or modern MySQL with proper settings).

In your case, if there's no last login, then `LastLoginTimestamp` should indeed be `NULL`. That's the sensible value for it. If you can't or won't do that for some reason, I recommend using the special timestamp value `-infinity`.

```
COALESCE(LastLoginTimestamp, TIMESTAMP '-infinity')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will return 1900-01-01 as `timestamp with time zone` in case when first argument of `coalesce` (`LastLoginTimestamp`) is `null`:

```
coalesce(LastLoginTimestamp,cast('1900-01-01' as timestamp with time zone))
```

Your attempt failed, because PostgreSQL does not know that you mean `timestamp` type by `''`. By default, PostgreSQL will assume `''` is text:

```
select coalesce(null,'')
```